# SSIS Package - Child packages are not getting executed

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

We have multiple Staging, Dimension, Fact packages - which were all running fine recently.

But from yesterday in Facts process - child packages are not getting executed from Parent. It invokes child package, but none of the task in CHILD gets executed, it just gets STUCK.

We havent made any changes to packages. But when I run child packages individually they work perfectly fine.

Is this a SSIS bug?

Regards

Comment: So you changed nothing, but what about the environment? Did a patch (OS or SQL) get applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, something must have been done. Even if it is a bug, the bug would not have emerged from nothing :)

If you guarantee that nothing was changed on the packages, I would say that something was done to the environment. Where are the packages deployed? SQL Server? Check the SSIS Service. File System? Check the path of the packages and specially config files.

It would be helpful if you post some more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check the `LOG` to see what happen or what is the reason of this problem.

The log entries can also be viewed from the Business intelligence Studio by opening the Log Events window from the SSIS menu.

You have also **many log providers** to help you to log all the packages events as:

- **The SQL Profiler log provider** Writes log files that you can view using SQL Profiler. The default file extension is .trc.
- **The SQL Server log provider** Writes log entries to the sysdtslog90 table in a SQL Server 2005 database.
- **The Windows Event log provider** Writes entries to the application log in the Windows Event log on the local computer.
- **The XML File log provider** Writes log files to an XML file. The default file extension is .xml.
- **The Text File log provider** Writes log entries to ASCII text files using a comma-separated value (CSV) format. The default file
  extension is .log.

For more information:
[check the section: SSIS Package Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966389.aspx)